# How to use cv2.warpperspective with only one source point [x,y]

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, transformation

I'm having a problem for just one point (x, y) of the image and having already calculated the transformation matrix on the two images calculate what the corresponding point (x, y) in the second image. 
If i have a pixel point [510,364] from my source image and de transformation matrix that i already calculate:

```
Matrix Transform:  [[ 7.36664511e-01  3.38845039e+01  2.17700574e+03]
[-1.16261372e+00  6.30840432e+01  8.09587058e+03]
[ 4.28933532e-05  8.15551141e-03  1.00000000e+00]]
```

i can get my new point : [3730,7635]

How can i do this?

```
h, status =cv2.findHomography(arraypoints_fire,arraypoints_vertical)

warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(fire_image_open, h, (vertical_image_open.shape[1],vertical_image_open.shape[0]))
cv2.namedWindow('Warped Source Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", warped_image)

cv2.namedWindow('Overlay', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
overlay_image=cv2.addWeighted(vertical_image_open,0.3,warped_image,0.8,0)
cv2.imshow('Overlay',overlay_image)
```

Comment: `cv2.perspectiveTransform()` will transform *points* --> https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same problem and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852182/running-cvwarpperspective-on-points), but on cpp. According [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87), opencv warpPerspective uses this formula, where

src - input image.

dst - output image that has the size dsize and the same type as src.

M - 3×3 transformation matrix (inverted).

[image]

You can use it directly on the point:

```
# M - transform matrix, created with cv2.perspectiveTransform

def warp_point(x: int, y: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    d = M[2, 0] * x + M[2, 1] * y + M[2, 2]

    return (
        int((M[0, 0] * x + M[0, 1] * y + M[0, 2]) / d), # x
        int((M[1, 0] * x + M[1, 1] * y + M[1, 2]) / d), # y
    )
```

UPD:
I've found one more [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399915/how-do-i-determine-the-locations-of-the-points-after-perspective-transform-in-t), but on python :D

It seems, I forgot brackets, in first part, fixed.

Comment: Using jit, you can increase speed of execution several times