# OpenCV warpPerspective error : Bad number of channels

Tags: c++, opencv

when using `warpPerspective`,

> OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4
>   channels) in cvConvertImage, file
>   /build/opencv-ys8xiq/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/utils.cpp,
>   line 622 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   /build/opencv-ys8xiq/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/utils.cpp:622:
>   error: (-15) Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels in function
>   cvConvertImage

But, the source image being used is 1 channel and has the desired size.

This code is basically to get the birdeye's view of an image.

```
cv::Mat warped;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> src  ;
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(640, 470));
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 470));
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(150, 250));
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(490, 250));


std::vector<cv::Point2f> dst  ;
dst.push_back(cv::Point2f(640, 480));
dst.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 480));
dst.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
dst.push_back(cv::Point2f(640, 0));

cv::Mat M = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src,dst);

cv::warpPerspective(src, warped, M, image.size());
```

Comment: src isnt an image but your point vector. try cv::warpPerspective(imahe, warped, M, ...) instead

Comment: Voting to close because the question is a simple typo; Micka is correct in that you're accidentally passing the points `src` instead of the `image`!

Comment: Yes alkasm. you are right

Answer (score 1):

It was discussed in topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863381

Short answer:

**Use cv::perspectiveTransform or matrix multiplication for points and cv::warpPerspective for images**

I hope it will help.

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue. I am using the cv::warpPerspective for an image, but I need the transformation matrix first. That is why I am using the cv::getperspectiveTransform.
I am doing the same in Python and runs without trouble. Thanks either way !

Comment: You can use matrix from getPerspectiveTransform in multiplication of points. This will help. Regards.